# Printing only the matter of a mail

Tags: javascript, html, email

I want to print only the matter of a mail.
when i am using `window.print()` it is printing the from and to address also, but I want to print only the matter
I have also gone through other posts in stack overflow but unable to meet the exact requirement, Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

place mail content on div then use jquery to print ..

```
$("mailcontent").printElement();
```

Comment: Thnx for your help, will the jquery code will run in any email server?

Comment: I have included a html table inside `<div id="mailcontent">`  and then i have called a function on a button onclick event like: `<FORM>
<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="prntml();">
</FORM>` and while constructing the email msg I have defined the function in `<head>` like you said  But no luck, it seems like the function is not calling, Am I doing something wrong?